# Reclassify Raster in R

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I have a raster image which contains the value of NDVI ranging from -0.2 to 0.6

```
NDVI  
#class      : RasterLayer 
#dimensions : 706, 953, 672818  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution : 30, 30  (x, y)
#extent     : 368085, 396675, 2038125, 2059305  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
#source     : memory
#names      : layer 
#values     : -0.08728454, 0.5357124  (min, max)
```

I need to reclassify this raster such as

- NDVI values < 0 -- 0.99
- NDVI Value > 0 and NDVI < 0.2  -- 0.96
- **NDVI value > 0.2 and NDVI < 0.5 =  0.004 * lsat8_PV + 0.986**

Where lsat8_pv is another raster which has been calculated in below format

```
 lsat8_pv <- ((ndvi - maxValue(ndvi)) / (maxValue(ndvi) - minValue(ndvi)))^2

 lsat8_pv
 #class      : RasterLayer 
 #dimensions : 706, 953, 672818  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
 #resolution : 30, 30  (x, y)
 #extent     : 368085, 396675, 2038125, 2059305  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
 #crs        : +proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
  #source     : memory
  #names      : layer 
  #values     : 0, 1  (min, max)
```

I have gone through some of the similar questions but was not able to spot any question wherein formula is specified under reclassification rules.

Below is what I tried

```
lsat_e[ndvi < 0] = 0.991
lsat_e[ndvi > 0 & ndvi < 0.2] = 0.966

e <-  ({0.004 * lsat8_PV} + 0.986)

m = cbind(from = c(-1, 0.2, 0.5), to = c(0.2, 0.5, 1), becomes = c(0.984, e , 0.99))
m
#     from to  becomes
#[1,] -1   0.2 0.984  
#[2,] 0.2  0.5 ?      
#[3,] 0.5  1   0.99
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a self-contained minimal reproducible example

```
library(raster)
ndvi <- raster(nrow=7, ncol=9, ext=extent(368085, 398085, 2038305, 2059305), crs="+proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84")
values(ndvi) <- seq(-1, 1, 2/ncell(ndvi))[-1]

maxVal <- cellStats(ndvi, max)
minVal <- cellStats(ndvi, min)
lsat8_pv <- ((ndvi - maxVal) / (maxVal - minVal))^2
```

And you should also be more clear about what you need. For example, what about the values above 0.5? Why does what you tried not use the same values as in your problem description?

Anyway, you can do something like this. Use, `reclassify`, but set the cells that need to be replaced by the values of another raster to NA. Then use `cover` for the replacement.

```
lst <- 0.004 * lsat8_pv + 0.986
m <- cbind(from = c(-Inf, 0, 0.2, 0.5), to = c(0, 0.2, 0.5, Inf), becomes = c(0.99, 0.96, NA , 1))
x <- reclassify(ndvi, m)
y <- cover(x, lsat8_pv)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will be more careful about posting question next time,  just a small doubt, in the last line of code, cover function, the NA values with 'x' raster will be replaced by another raster named 'lsat8_pv'?